# Smart way of finding the polygon intersection of a huge GeoJSON file with a small GeoJSON file without looping through all polygons

Tags: polygon, intersection, turf

I have a huge GeoJSON file (over 300MB) which has multiple different polygons. Also, I have a very small GeoJSON file with only one polygon that doesn't have more than ten points. Using the [intersection function from turf.js](https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect), I can create a simple logic where I loop through all polygons inside my huge GeoJSON file and I try to find which of its polygons intersect with my small GeoJSON file. This is a functional logic, but I'm not sure if that's how I'm supposed to solve this kind of problem.

What would be a smarter way of solving this problem?

How can I find which of my polygons (inside a huge file) intersect with a small polygon (inside my small file) without searching if there's an intersection in all polygons?

Even though I'm using `turf.js` with `node.js` I'm not stuck with this library and language. So, if there's a better way of solving it with python or command line I can change my approach for solving this problem. I think I'm missing a concept for solving problems with this kind of scale.

Comment: I think that the smart way is called spatial index. GeoJSON does not support indexing so you must convert it first into something that does. That does not need to be another format if there is enough memory to store the data.

Comment: @user30184 I see... So two of my alternatives here would be importing those files to a PostgreSQL database using PostGIS or using gpkg files with geopandas in python? What would be an example of a file format that supports the creation of a spatial index?

Comment: Probably there are other alternatives. Search for example where and how this library is used https://libspatialindex.org/en/latest/.